# Cosos2d-X Build Android X86 Errors?

Tags: android, c++, compilation, cocos2d-x

When I run the command

```
cocos compile -p android --ap android-15 --app-abi x86
```

I get the error

```
/audio/android/cutils/bitops.h: In function 'int bitmask_ffz(unsigned int*, int)':
/audio/android/cutils/bitops.h:65:30: error: 'ffs' was not declared in this scope

 bit = ffs(~bitmask[i]);
                          ^

[x86] Compile++      : audioengine_static <= AudioDecoderProvider.cpp

make: ** [obj/local/x86/objs-debug/audioengine_static/AudioDecoder.o] Error 1

make: ** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

make: Leaving directory `/DeneOyun/proj.android'

**Error running command, return code: 2.**
```

Comment: you can try with compile .py file from proj.android and make sure you delete the obj folder

Comment: @AjayPandya it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You probably upgraded NDK to version 15.

Add the following to your Android.mk:

```
APP_DEPRECATED_HEADERS := true
```

for more details: [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-r15-release/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md)

Comment: With no problems = android-23, Is not causing ? = android-15

Comment: Yes, now it works well. But it was necessary to correct other mistakes.